# Rails arel grouping and counting with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given I have a Members table :

```
id   membername
-------------------
1    Fred
2    Dave
3    Jenny
```

and a Jobs table

```
id   member_id   status
1    1           Closed
2    2           Pending
3    2           Open
4    3           Pending
5    3           Pending
```

I want to output the total number of Pending jobs by member.

So with the above data, I'd like:

```
membername  count
Dave        1
Jenny       2
```

I can grab the counts using the group method, eg

```
Job.where("status = ?", "Pending").group(:member_id).count
```

but this doesn't return the names.  Just a hash of member_id's and counts.  I'm thinking I need to join this result to the members table somehow.  I can do this with raw SQL of course, but was wondering if there is a neater arel way of grabbing this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Job.where("status = ?", "Pending").joins(:member).group("member.name").count
```